# Why the QNetworkReply readAll() returns zero bytes?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I am using qtwebkit in pyqt4  to download images through QNetworkReply:

```
import os 
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class dxBrowser(QWebPage):
def __init__(self,url):
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self._url=url
    self.manager=self.networkAccessManager()
    self.connect(self.manager,SIGNAL("finished(QNetworkReply *)"),self.onFinished)

def crawl(self):
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(self._url))

def onFinished(self,networkReply):
    if networkReply.rawHeader('Content-Type')=='image/png':
        print 'find the image'
        l=int(networkReply.rawHeader('Content-Length'))
        print l
        byteArray=networkReply.readAll()
        print byteArray.size()
        im=QImage.fromData(byteArray)
        if not im.save('test.jpg','jpg'):
            print 'image save error'


def main():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    url='http://www.yiyaows.cn/DrsPath.do?kid=6666686E686E69673334333632303335&username=mylibddrz&spagenum=251&pages=50&fid=7534992&a=95cb07394dbf1d43c1fe61bdf6d4a36d&btime=2011-08-19&etime=2011-09-08&template=bookdsr1&firstdrs=http%3A%2F%2Fbook1.duxiu.com%2FbookDetail.jsp%3FdxNumber%3D000005609810%26d%3DA30222298F3C6715323B5476CB66D650'
    dx=dxBrowser(url)
    dx.crawl()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Though the content-length is non-zero but the byteArray.size() is 0. So I can't save the image. Why? Can anyone help me.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I figured this out. The qtwebkit may have retrieve the content of the qnetworkreply, a QIODevice, the size of it would be 0 after readall().Maybe the qtwebkit as a browser has read it for rendering, I guess.

Comment: Where does that `reply` attribute on dxBrowser come from?

Comment: Sorry,the previous code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: Maybe I figured this out. The qtwebkit may have retrieve the
>   content of the qnetworkreply, a QIODevice, the size of it would be 0
>   after readall().Maybe the qtwebkit as a browser has read it for
>   rendering, I guess.

Yes and there is an easy work-around: add a `QNetworkDiskCache` to the manager (with [`QNetworkAccessManager.setCache`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager.html#PySide.QtNetwork.PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.setCache)) and retrieve the image from the cache in your slot `onFinished`.

If the website uses "Pragma: no-cache" or "Cache-control" to hint the browser not to save the file to disk, you will have to redefine the method `prepare` (and maybe `updateMetaData`) of `QNetworkDiskCache` to override the flag `saveToDisk` before calling the original method(s).

Comment: After setting the cache, does the QNetworkAccessManager instance automatically write to that cache? Or do you have to manually insert after each request?

Comment: @izyda You only have to call `setCache` once, and it works immediately for any new request after being set.

Comment: this worked out great but now I've returned to the "Pragma: no-cache" or "Cache-control" problem. Could you give me a few pointers as to how I should be approach this? Should I create a Python class that inherits from ```QNetworkDiskCache``` and just overwrites the prepare method?